# Is it possible to install the PostGIS to the PostgreSQL (binary version)?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm using the PostgreSQL 9.2.4 which is the no installation version.I run this by using the command "Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/pg_ctl" -D "Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/data" -l "Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/log/pgsql.log" start"!

And I tried to install the PostGIS 1.5.5 into the PostgreSQL server. It is not work! The template_postgis is created, but no tables was generated in the table folder!

Would like to confirm, does the PostGIS need to be installed to installion version instead of binary version? Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: You can install Postgis 1.5.5, if you use postgres 9.0
see http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg90/ .

If you use PostgreSQL 9.2.4, you must install postgis 2.0.3 http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg92/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PostgreSQL 9.2 is only compatible with Postgis 2.0 or superior](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS). After postgis installation you can use [the extensions system](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions) to enable the spatial capabilities of a database.